compose Scroll jumps up after navigating
https://github.com/android/nowinandroid/issues/936
I am encountering the same issue described here and am trying to fix it.
I am using val scrollState = rememberLazyListState() at the top level to remember the scroll position. However, this issue only occurs at the bottom of the list.
//Main Activity
WindowCompat.setDecorFitsSystemWindows(window, false)

in Jetpack Compose, I encountered the same issue as seen in "Now in Android." After testing, downgrading the material3 version to 1.1.0-rc01 seemed to resolve the issue.
I am unsure if this is a bug in Google's library or an error on my part. Does anyone have any insights or similar experiences related to this issue?
